# Typescript Jest says mock or mockReturnedValue do not exist on types I wish to mock

Tags: typescript, axios, jestjs, mocking

Here's a class I wish to test:

```
//Request.js
import axios, {AxiosInstance} from 'axios';
import config from './config';

const axiosSingleton: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080',
});

export default class Request {
  public async get<$ResponseType = any>(url: string): Promise<void> {
    const response = await axiosSingleton.get(url);
    return response.data;
  }
}
```

when I try testing this by creating a test file, I am not sure how to mock axios. I tried a bunch of ways including - spyOn and automatic mocking. But they don't seem to work. Here's a version of the test file I am not understanding why it doesn't work

```
// Request.test.js
import axios from 'axios';
import Request from './Request';

interface ITestResponseDataType {
  value: string
}

jest.mock('axios');

describe('Request Tests', () => {
  it('should call axios get with the right relativeUrl', async () => {
    const getMock = jest.fn();

    axios.create.mockReturnValue({
      get: getMock
    });

    getMock.mockResolvedValue({
      value: 'value'
    });

    const data = await new Request().get<ITestResponseDataType>('/testUrl');
    expect(getMock.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
    expect(data).toEqual({
      value: 'value'
    });
  });
});
```

The error I get when I try running the test is -

```
 TypeScript diagnostics (customize using `[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics` option):
    src/common/api/Request.test.ts:15:18 - error TS2339: Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type '(config?: AxiosRequestConfig | undefined) => AxiosInstance'.

    15     axios.create.mockReturnValue({
```

This error makes sense, because the type defined in axios for axios.create should not allow .mockReturnValue to be called on .create. So how do I tell typescript that jest has gone in and modified it?

Comment: I got the same error and stumbled over here... it turned out for my mocked function I wasnt actually invoking jest.fn()

Answer (score 90):

Cast the mock method to `jest.Mock`, ie

```js
import axios from "axios"
import Request from "./Request";

// Create an Axios mock
// Don't worry about the order, Jest will hoist this above the imports
// See https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports
jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  create: jest.fn()
}))

// Customise the `create` mock method
(axios.create as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue({
  get: getMock
})
```

---

An even easier solution is to use [jest.mocked()](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#jestmockedsource-options)

> The `mocked()` helper method wraps types of the `source` object and its deep nested members with type definitions of Jest mock function.

```ts
jest.mocked(axios.create).mockReturnValue({ get: getMock });
```

Comment: This doesn't work for when the module / file being tested is calling the "Mocked" function globally, like in @ashwini 's case `const axiosSingleton: AxiosInstance = axios.create(...)`.
Moving the AxiosInstance to a local variable in the functions works, but now you're not using the singleton.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @DanB When you use `jest.mock`, it will hoist the mock instance above any imports so it will also be used in the production files during testing

Answer (score 9):

Just an addition to top rated answer. I would prefer maintaining type definitions when type casting. That can be be rewritten as

```
(axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>).create.mockReturnValue({
  get: getMock
});
```

Comment: Didn't work for me: 
```
Argument of type '{ get: jest.Mock<any, any>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AxiosInstance'.
  Type '{ get: Mock<any, any>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AxiosInstance': defaults, interceptors, getUri, request, and 6 more.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the axios.create method with a Jest mock function:

```
axios.create = jest.fn();
```

That should allow you to then set its return value.

Answer (score 2):

This example is for a different library, but similar task. After casting the import to `jest.Mocked<typeof MyImport>`, I then needed to just assign mock functions to it's properties, as opposed to using the `mockReturnValue` method. At least this is one viable approach.

```js
import Reactotron from '../../reactotron'
import { makeEnhancers } from './enhancers'

jest.mock('../../reactotron')
const mockReactotron = Reactotron as jest.Mocked<typeof Reactotron>

describe('makeEnhancers', () => {
  describe('given Reactotron createEnhancer exists', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      mockReactotron.createEnhancer = jest.fn()
    })
    it('appends the reactotron enhancer', () => {
      const enhancers = makeEnhancers()
      expect(enhancers).toHaveLength(1)
    })
  })

  describe('given Reactotron createEnhancer does not exist', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      mockReactotron.createEnhancer = undefined
    })
    it('does not append the reactotron enhancer', () => {
      const enhancers = makeEnhancers()
      expect(enhancers).toHaveLength(0)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with axios-mock-adapter, works for me without any problem and also helps with nested calls.

```
    // src/request.ts
    import axios from "axios";
    export const axiosCreate = axios.create();
    export async function someRequest(){
      axiosCreate.get("http://localhost/users");
    }

    // src/__test__/request.test.ts
    import * as request from ".../request";
    import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";
    const mock = new MockAdapter(request.axiosCreate);
    it("Testing mock", async () => {
      mock.onGet("http://locahost/users").reply(200, "ok");
      const resp = await request.someRequest();
      expect(resp).toEqual("ok");
    });
```

Hopefully can help to someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
import axios from 'axios';
jest.mock('axios');
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;

beforeEach(() => {
jest.resetAllMocks();
mockedAxios.get.mockResolvedValue({
data: []
});
});
```

For me only this way was the axios mock funtional