Toggle Jest mock from returning value and throwing error
I am putting in some basic unit tests for my usage of AWS DynamoDB. I have the happy path tests running, however I'm now wanting to test the catch block which will need me to throw an error from part of the process, and I'm wondering how I can alter my existing code to do this.
Is it possible to the toggle the mocked response from being a proper response to an error?
db.ts:
export const getData = async () => {
  const command = new GetItemCommand({ ... });

  try {
    return await client.send(command);
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(`some error here`);
  }
};

db.unit.ts:
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb', () => ({
  GetItemCommand: jest.fn(() => true),
  DynamoDBClient: jest.fn(() => ({ send: jest.fn(() => 'get success') })),
}));

it('should get from db', async () => {
  const res = await getData();
  expect(res).toBe('get success');
});

it('should throw error when getting from db', async () => {
  const res = await getData();
  expect(res).toThrow('Some error thrown'); // Will be false as the mock always returns the 'get success' 
});

I attempted to follow how to change jest mock function return value in each test? but it seemed like I couldn't get it working as they had, and in fact my previously working tests have now started failing.
import {GetItemCommand, UpdateItemCommand, DynamoDBClient} from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';

jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb', () => ({
  GetItemCommand: jest.fn(),
  DynamoDBClient: jest.fn(() => ({ send: jest.fn(() => 'get success') })),
}));

it('should put things in db', async () => {
  UpdateItemCommand.mockReturnValueOnce(true);
  const res = await getResults();
  expect(res).toBe('get success');
});

In the above, my IDE is complaining about UpdateItemCommand.mockReturnValueOnce(true) stating that
Property mockReturnValueOnce does not exist on type typeof UpdateItemCommand


Yes, of course that's possible. You just need to get access to the jest.fn() object, e.g. by importing it, then can call the usual methods to control how it responds to interaction.

This question is similar to: how to change jest mock function return value in each test?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@jonrsharpe I've looked at the question linked but can't get a similar experience... I've updated the question at the bottom with further info.

So you research that error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51495473/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/53225236/3001761, ... The actual UpdateItemCommand indeed does not have a mockReturnValueOnce method, so the compiler needs to know that's a mocked version of it.

(In fact in what you've actually shown UpdateItemCommand isn't a mock function either...)

Hmm... I'm trying various things from what you've suggested but I'm not sure I'm quite getting it :-(

@jonrsharpe - Any chance I can get a bit more of your help on this?

"not sure I'm quite getting it" isn't really a problem SO can solve. If you can [edit] to provide a [mre] of a problem that's not already posted here, please do.

@jonrsharpe I haven't seen the issue posted anywhere. The ones you've listed don't fit the bill. They look similar, but clearly not the same issue.

They're not clearly not the same issue. If you can make that clear, please do so. So far it's unclear how you're failing to fit them to the bill.
